# Philz touch 6 stuck in recovery mode

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-lite

I recently installed philz touch 6 recovery on my galaxy tab 3 lite, with the main purpose of rooting.

When I downloaded it over ODIN it was fine, and booted into recovery.

Now, when I try to boot (at all) it goes to recovery when I want to use the OS (without pressing any buttons other than POWER) it boots to recovery still. any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the `goya` board.

Steps to solve this:

1. Download the official TWRP recovery for this device. [Download Link](https://twrp.me/samsung/goya.html)
2. Boot into recovery.
3. Go to Advanced > Terminal.
4. Type in `busybox reboot` and press Enter on the virtual keyboard. This will make the device boot back into system.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a backup and reflash a stock ROM for your ROM or flash a different recovery for your phone. Also take a look at these sites.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2426426
http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/369146-only-boots-into-recovery-mode.html
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1794153

Comment: Where can I find the stock ROM for my tab 3 lite, without having to download a virus?

Comment: Haha lol! I use the site Sammobile, it's a site for all the samsung devices. Just create an account and you can download a stock firmware for your device. http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/

Comment: Have you already tried to flash a different recovery in download mode with odin?

Answer (score 0):

FLash TWRP Recovery and from there go to Reboot ---> Bootloader